Branching and Merging issues in SVN
We have a Prod, UAT, Emer_Fix branch which are static/permanent - meaning they never close and live forever.
We also have two TEST and a DEV branch which fit this same model.
Current Model:
1 permanent PRODUCTION branch
1 permanent UAT branch
1 permanent EMER_FIX branch
2 permanent TEST branches
2 non-permanent TEST Branches (with possible child dev branch)
1 permanent DEV branch
On top of that we sometimes have two other branches created as a new branch off of UAT - this gets closed when the project is completed.
We work very waterfall - and mostly "one or two at a time"... Meaning the Project goes through the cycle before a new project is moved to test:
DEV -> Test -> UAT -> PROD
Sometimes we have new projects committed in DEV before testing is finished - if these are in the same file and bugs are found in PROJECT 1 in TEST, then Project 1 and Project 2 then become molded together and will go to UAT/PROD at the same time.
We have two "product lines" which are mostly their own code but once in a while touch the same file.
We GENERALLY work Product A in TEST1 and Product B in Test 2, but this is not always the case.
Within the last three years we've grown from 2 developers (1 in each product) to 10 developers - so a much higher volume of items being coded, often times in the same files and therefore an increased number of conflicts.
There are a few main struggles we're having.

At what point should code that came from a DEV branch be merged to the other TEST environments that it is not a child of. (IMG1) Should it be merged down when it goes to the UAT branch? Or PROD?

What is supposed to be done with the revisions that came from the branch you're merging back to?
EX: Code is committed in DEV. Code is merged to TEST. --> When you initiate a Merge from TEST to DEV, that revision is listed as a mergeable item.
Currently we merge these as "HISTORY ONLY" to get them off the list ... is this the correct way to handle?

What about when there is a conflict when merging down? Assuming it should then be included on the merge back up... but we get tree conflicts. (IMG2)
EX. File A (version 1), B and C are coded in DEV. File A(Version 2), D and E are coded in TEST2.
DEV is merged to TEST and then to UAT.
When we merge that down to TEST2, File A has conflicts which creates File A (Version 3). If we don't include the revision from the Merge Down - we get the conflicts again. However, if we do include it, we get Tree Conflicts on Files B and C (which we ignore with working copy).
What is the correct way to handle this?


Or are we just completely doing this wrong and there's a better solution to all of our merging woes?
When should code be merged to parallel branches
how to handle conflicts when merging down

Not an svn user myself but I am curious. The fact that you are getting conflicts does not surprise me as it is something you should expect if you are hitting the same sections of code in different branches. Are you getting unexpected conflicts? In my experience at least, conflicts are not something you are able to reduce by just changing workflows... what can change is the size and number of of conflicting sections... say, if you have merges/rebases more often, you should expect to get fewer/smaller conflicts....

... but given that you are doing merges/rebases more often that means that you will have more changes of producing those fewer/smaller conflicts.
